# Issues debugging JavaFX app in NetBeans

Tags: debugging, javafx, netbeans

I'm writting a pretty simple 2D sprite game engine, and I'e run into an issue with debugging in NetBeans.  Originally, I wrote the engine using Swing because that's all I had experience working with, and everything ran fine, but it was a little slow when I had a lot to render to the screen.

So, I decided to switch over rendering to something more modern and settled on JavaFX, after a suggestion here.  The conversion went pretty smooth, but I noticed my methods for handling animation weren't working.  That's not an issue, I can fix that.  Or I could, if I could get the debugger in NetBeans to work.
Every time I try to run the debugger, first the line marker that shows what line I'm actually on doesn't show up.  Then, when I try to move to the next line, the debugger immediately jumps to a file in the JavaFX package called LauncherImpl.java, and at that point the line marker shows up.  I eventually get stuck in a loop at lines 93 to 103 in `InvokeLateDispatcher.java` that the debugger just keeps cycling through, and I can't get out of it and back to my actual code.  Even 'step out' does nothing.
This is very frustrating, since I know I can fix my animations if I could actually see what is happening.  I've tried using breakpoints, running to cursor, everything I can think of but the end result is the same.  Stuck in a package file I don't care about and unable to troubleshoot my code.  I don't know if this has something to do with using an `AnimationTimer` for my game loop or what.
Does anyone have any ideas?  Maybe a way to keep the debugger from entering files that aren't physically part of the project?  I'm at a loss.

Comment: Conceptually, at least, there is a loop in the FX Application Thread that repeatedly checks if event handlers need to be invoked, invokes any runnables submitted to `Platform.runLater(...)`, and checks if it is time to re-render the scene. Only if it's time to do that, the scene gets re-rendered, and that will include calling your `AnimationTimer.handle()` method. It sounds like you may have got stuck iterating through the main loop which only rarely invokes `handle()`. Maybe try resuming at the bottom of your `handle()` method and letting it hit the breakpoint again next time it's invoked?

Comment: Debugger marking wrong/non-existent lines may mean you are running an older version of your code. Try doing a clean build, it may help.